# How to combine two rows into one?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to combine two rows into one.

```
EMPCode  actHours    actDate     rowno
107 8.00        2013-01-21  1
107 8.30        2013-01-22  1
107 4.00        2013-01-23  1
107 4.00        2013-01-23  2
107 4.10        2013-01-24  1
107 4.20        2013-01-24  2
107 4.30        2013-01-25  1
107 4.30        2013-01-25  2

I want the result as follows:

actHours    actDate 
8.00        2013-01-21 
8.30        2013-01-22
8.00        2013-01-23 
8.30        2013-01-24
9.00        2013-01-25
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(actHours) actHours, actDate FROM Tbl GROUP BY actDate
```

Actually, if you provide datatypes of the columns, the answer can be more concrete.

Comment: thanks for reply..actually the datatype of actHours is numeric(5,2)

Answer (score 0):

what if data contains these..

```
108 3.40        2013-01-26  1
108 3.50        2013-01-26  2
```

if datatype is `time`, then u can use this query..

```
with datecte
as
(
 SELECT actDate,  SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '0:00:00', actHours)) actHours
 FROM Tb1
 GROUP BY actDate
)
SELECT actDate,
actHours = RTRIM(actHours/60) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(actHours%60),2)
FROM datecte
```

Comment: @ram Instead of posting as different answer,try to edit your single post and specify different solutions to the problem in the `same` post

Answer (score 0):

use this then,

```
with datecte
as
(
 select  actDate, SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '0:00:00', actHours)) actHours
 from (
   SELECT actDate,CAST(REPLACE(actHours,'.',':') as time) actHours
   FROM #tb1
      ) k 
 group by actDate
)


SELECT actDate,
actHours = RTRIM(actHours/60) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(actHours%60),2)
FROM datecte
```

Hope this gives you solution..

OK @praveen..